# Laravel Pusher Error "No Callback" Error

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, pusher

I am trying to build real time Notifications using Laravel 5.3 and Pusher for my Web-Applicatin. I am able to push messages to Pusher debug console.
My Server-side script:

```
$options = array(
                    'cluster' => 'ap2',
                    'encrypted' => true
            );
            $pusher = new Pusher(
                    'xxxxxxxxxx', // removed for safety
                    'xxxxxxxxxx', // removed for safety
                    'xxxxx', // removed for safety
                    $options
            );

            $data['message'] = ($user->name)." like your status";
            $pusher->trigger('my-channel', 'PusherEvent', $data);
```

And my Client-side Script:

```
<script src="https://js.pusher.com/4.0/pusher.min.js"></script>
```

```
// Enable pusher logging - don't include this in production
Pusher.logToConsole = true;

var pusher = new Pusher('xxxxxxxxx', {
  cluster: 'ap2',
  encrypted: true
});

var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
channel.bind('PusherEvent', function(data) {
  alert(data.message);
});
```

I want to get alert on my webpage.Javascript is enabled in my browser.My browser console shows something like this:

```
Pusher : Event sent : {"event":"pusher:subscribe","data":{"channel":"my-channel"}} pusher.min.js:8:2594
Pusher : Event recd : {"event":"pusher_internal:subscription_succeeded","data":{},"channel":"my-channel"}
Pusher : No callbacks on my-channel for pusher:subscription_succeeded
```

What might be the reason for this ??

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any bindings for an event called `pusher_internal:subscription_succeeded`. This is normal and nothing to worry about. When you subscribe to a channel an event is fired which you aren't listening for.

If you got an event called `PusherEvent` and got that callback message you should be concerned.